# Setting up server authentication for android inapp billing

Tags: php, android, mysql, in-app-purchase

Is there any example code for php server and Android client setup.like mentioned in  [google best practices](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html)? The server client handshake should exist as well.

Any ideas? I am interested in both setups Php and android.